# Why is my LED blinking?

Tags: arduino-uno, button

I have this simple push button schematic:
[image]

The idea is that the LED is on as long as the button stays pushed, with the switch closed.

The code is below:

```
int ledPin=10;
int switchPin=5;

void setup()

{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(switchPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin,OUTPUT);

}
void loop()

{
  digitalWrite(ledPin,LOW);//DBG
  if (digitalRead(switchPin)==HIGH)
{
 digitalWrite(ledPin,HIGH);//DBG
 delay(500);
}
 if (digitalRead(switchPin)==LOW);
{
digitalWrite(ledPin,LOW);//DBG 
delay(200);
}
}
```

As I keep the button pressed, **the LED blinks regularly**, instead of **staying on**. Why?
I have tried using a capacitor between the switch and switchPin, with no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beginning of your code in the loop:

```cpp
void loop()  {
  digitalWrite(ledPin,LOW); //remove this line here
  if (digitalRead(switchPin)==HIGH)
{
     digitalWrite(ledPin,HIGH);//DBG
     delay(500);
}
 if (digitalRead(switchPin)==LOW);
 {
      digitalWrite(ledPin,LOW);//DBG 
       delay(200);
     }
}
```

Before your first `if(digital read(switch pin) == HIGH)`  you turn the LED off, and then you have a delay, which gives the blinking effect, remove that and it will not blink.

Comment: @GiuseppeBarbesino not stupid just the formating of the code makes it unreadable, and will cause one to miss read code, happens to many ;)